# How to count the number of ways $10$ apples and $10$ orange can be distributed among $10$ people under the following conditions

Tags: combinatorics

How to count the number of ways $10$ apples and $10$ oranges can be distributed among $10$ people. Options - one person can have nothing, can have one or more apples, one or more oranges. One person can not have both an orange and apple.

My best approach is have one person have $10$ apples and then distribute $10$ oranges among $9$ persons. Then have two persons have $10$ apples and distribute oranges among $8$. Then sum all these cases. That I can do. I wonder if there is a more concise way.

Comment: If you don't mind brute force or computer assistance, you can look at the coefficient of $x^{10}y^{10}$ in the expansion of $(1+x+y+x^2+y^2+x^3+y^3+\dots+x^{10}+y^{10})^{10}$.  Otherwise, I would have done the same thing you propose with the summation.

Answer (score 2):

In your approach you don’t say whether you allow $0$ fruit to be distributed when you distribute the apples and the oranges. If you allow this option for both apples and oranges, then you overcount because each person with $0$ fruit is counted once as getting no apples and once as getting no oranges. If you allow this option for neither apples nor orange, then you undercount because no one can get $0$ fruit.

The answer by Alborz solves this by never distributing $0$ fruit to people but having two separate variables for the people who get apples and the people who get oranges; but that leads to an unneccessary double sum.

The efficient solution is to allow $0$ fruit to be distributed in one case but not in the other. So let $m$ be the number of people who actually get apples. Then there are $\binom{10}m$ ways to choose these people, $\binom{10-1}{m-1}$ ways to distribute the $10$ apples to them (not allowing $0$ fruit) and $\binom{10+10-m-1}{10-m-1}$ ways to distribute the $10$ oranges to the remaining $10-m$ people (allowing $0$ fruit), for a total of

$$
\sum_{m=1}^9\binom{10}m\binom{10-1}{m-1}\binom{10+10-m-1}{10-m-1}=135916002\;.
$$

Regarding your actual question: I don’t see a more concise way to do this.

Comment: I don't count people who get nothing, if you distribute 10 apples and 10 oranges among 10 people, then you are left with 0 to 8 people who have nothing and you can't distribute nothing among them but the way it already is, so its a factor of one, you don't count it. Am I wrong?

Comment: @ivanptiukhin: That's not what you wrote in the question. In the question you wrote "have one person have $10$ apples and then distribute $10$ oranges among $9$ persons. Then have two persons have $10$ apples and distribute oranges among $8$". So the number of people among whom you distributed apples and oranges always added up to $10$. That was the basis of my comment on your approach. If you don't make those numbers add up to $10$, then you get the approach in Alborz' answer.

Comment: Yes, distribute them so that a person can get an orange or oranges or nothing.

Comment: @ivanptiukhin: Yeah, that's what my answer does. As I wrote, I don't think you'll get anything more concise than that.

Answer (score 1):

I will refer to Theorem $1$ of the stars and bars concept https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Assuming all $10$ apples and $10$ oranges have to be distributed:

Let $x$ be the number of people who get apples, then $1\leq x \leq 9$, and there are $10\choose x$ ways to pick the $x$ people who are receiving apples. By Theorem $1$, there are ${10-1}\choose{x-1}$ ways to distribute these $10$ apples among these $x$ people.

Similarly, let $y$ be the number of people who get oranges, then $1\leq y \leq 10-x$. Then there are ${10-x}\choose y$ ways to pick the people who get oranges, and ${10-1}\choose{y-1}$ ways to distribute the $10$ oranges among the $y$ people receiving oranges.

The $10-x-y$ remaining people receive nothing in exactly $1$ way.

Finally, we must sum over all valid choices of $x, y$ so we get that the total number of ways is $$\sum_{x=1}^{9} {{10}\choose {x}}{{9}\choose {x-1}}(\sum_{y=1}^{10-x}{{10-x}\choose {y}}{{9}\choose {y-1}}) = 135,916,002$$

Note that I have just formalized and performed the computations for the approach you mentioned so it's arguably not 'more concise'. So maybe this doesn't answer the question. However, in reaching the final result you may be able to manipulate the sums and products to achieve a more concise result

Comment: X cannot be equal to 10 since there will not be people left to have oranges. You assumed right that all fruit have to be distributed.

Comment: @ivanptiukhin right, my mistake. Edited that

Comment: The factor in parentheses (which, by the way, you could get to adapt to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left`and `\right`) is just $\binom{19-x}{9-x}$, the number of ways to distribute the $10$ oranges to $10-x$ people while allowing some to get none.

Comment: @joriki nice, that simplifies things